# How to create a dropdownlist for login page in Ast.NET core MVC?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to hide the "Profile" or all the logged in information under a dropdownlist.
I want to have the logged in user infos to be placed in a dropdowlist. 
Therefor, I tried to change the _LoginPartial.cshtml code in the Asp.NET Core MVC, but it looks not what it supposed to be.

Can someone please help me with correcting this piece of code.

The line of code that i added starts with

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">@UserManager.GetUserName(User)!<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

and underneath that is the original MVC generated code, which is commented out.

```
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">@UserManager.GetUserName(User)!<span class="caret"></span></a>
                @*<li> <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a> </li>*@
                <ul>
                    <li> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Logout</button>  </li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

It looks like this. I want to have the circles to be removed, too.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue: In case somebody desires to have a dropdownlist for users in asp.net core.

```
 <form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">@UserManager.GetUserName(User) <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">My Loans</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>


                    <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Logout</button></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>           
        </ul>
    </form>
```